# How can I check my textarea at first and display something using JS after run the website immediately

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my HTML and JS Code:

```js
function errorMessage(){
if(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')['shipAddress'].value==''){
  document.getElementById('shipSubtotal').style.cssText='color: red; font-weight: bold;';
  document.getElementById('total').style.cssText='color: red; font-weight: bold;';
  document.getElementById('shipSubtotal').innerHTML='Please enter your address.';
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML='Please enter your address.';
}
else{
  document.getElementById('shipSubtotal').innerHTML='';
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML='';
}  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div>
  <p>
     Shipping Address: <br>
     <textarea name="shipAddress" id="addressInput" cols="30" rows="5"
     placeholder="Please enter your address." onchange="errorMessage()"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
     Merchandse Subtotal:
     <span id="merchandSubtotal"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
     Shipping Subtotal:
     <span id="shipSubtotal"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
     Total Payment: 
     <span id="total"></span>
  </p>
  <p> <input type="submit" value="Checkout" onclick="checkoutButton()"> </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issues are when I run the site, it doesn't call the errorMessage() at first, instead, I need to write something in the textarea box and clear it only will call this function. 
How can I overcome this so that it straight call the function immediately after running the site?
[image: Left site is what I want the after I run]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
    errorMessage();
})
```

Comment: Oh, genius! Thank you so much! so basically, this DOMContentLoaded is used for anything when the program is running. Thank you so much!